# How to get std::vector pointer to the raw data?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I'm trying to use `std::vector` as a `char` array.

My function takes in a void pointer:

```
void process_data(const void *data);
```

Before I simply just used this code:

```
char something[] = "my data here";
process_data(something);
```

Which worked as expected.

But now I need the dynamicity of `std::vector`, so I tried this code instead:

```
vector<char> something;
*cut*
process_data(something);
```

The question is, how do I pass the char vector to my function so I can access the vector raw data (no matter which format it is – floats, etc.)?

I tried this:

```
process_data(&something);
```

And this:

```
process_data(&something.begin());
```

But it returned a pointer to gibberish data, and the latter gave warning: `warning C4238: nonstandard extension used : class rvalue used as lvalue`.

Answer (score 278, accepted):

`&something` gives you the address of the `std::vector` object, not the address of the data it holds.  `&something.begin()` gives you the address of the iterator returned by `begin()` (as the compiler warns, this is not technically allowed because `something.begin()` is an rvalue expression, so its address cannot be taken).

Assuming the container has at least one element in it, you need to get the address of the initial element of the container, which you can get via

- `&something[0]` or `&something.front()` (the address of the element at index 0), or
- `&*something.begin()` (the address of the element pointed to by the iterator returned by `begin()`).

In C++11, a new member function was added to `std::vector`:  `data()`.  This member function returns the address of the initial element in the container, just like `&something.front()`.  The advantage of this member function is that it is okay to call it even if the container is empty.

Comment: **Important** Beware of `vector<bool>` which is the exception to this answer (and doesn't have a contiguous memory storage of `bool`s).

Comment: On the bright side, there's not much to beware of:  all three of these methods will fail to compile with `std::vector<bool>` because `std::vector<bool>` requires the use of a proxy object and that proxy can't be implicitly converted to a `bool*`.  As the workaround for this, if you do need a sequence of `bool`, it's best just to use a `std::vector<char>`.  @Motti

Comment: True, the _beware_ was in general and not directed as your answer, since there is no contiguous memory storage there is no way to get at it.

Comment: up for being comprehensive but mainly for `.data()` - I'lll just pretend I didn't see that ugly `&*iterator` :P

Comment: how long will the pointer returned from `data()` live? If the vector is never resized either larger or smaller (via `push_back()` or other functions, including `reserve`), is it guaranteed that the pointer will live as long as the vector lives, pointing to the correct place?

Comment: FYI, Scott Meyer's book "Effective STL" (for C++98) covers this topic in great depth in "Item 16: Know how to pass vector and string data to legacy APIs".

Comment: Note that it is indeed safe to call data() on an empty vector, but its result is mostly useless. It will point to some memory, even though there are no elements in the vector which may be unexpected.

Comment: @johnbakers For your concerns, `std::vector::reserve` is the only way to make sure the pointers are valid even when adding items to the container. Otherwise, you will get dangling pointers.

Answer (score 97):

`something.data()` will return a pointer to the data space of the vector.

Comment: `error C2039: 'data' : is not a member of 'std::vector<_Ty>'`

Comment: @Rookie: looks like you're using a broken compiler -- 23.3.6.3 in the C++ spec defines vector::data.  Try filing a bug with your vendor or getting a better compiler.

Comment: @Chris Dodd I've the same error. I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: `vector::data()` is new to C++11

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2012 and they must have added the vector::data() because I use it a bunch.

Comment: I liked sth.data() but recently I have to roll back to &sth.front().  We have a system that only supports g++34 ...

Answer (score 13):

Take a pointer to the first element instead:

```
process_data (&something [0]);
```

Comment: I thought that it would return the memory address of the first item even without the subscript brackets?

Comment: That's for arrays, not for vectors.

Comment: Yeah just realized that, sorry.