# gsl linear fitting using vectors

Tags: c++, vector, gsl

I have started with an example of [gsl fitting examples](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Fitting-Examples.html#Fitting-Examples) and tried to change the arrays to vectors. but when I compile my code, it leads to an error of this, which I dont understand and dont know what is wrong with my code, i appreciate any comment in advance:

example1.cpp:19:73: error: cannot convert ‘std::vector’ to ‘const double*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int gsl_fit_linear(const double*, size_t, const double*, size_t, size_t, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*)’
  gsl_fit_linear (x, 1, y, 1, n, &c0, &c1, &cov00, &cov01, &cov11, &sumsq);

and this is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <gsl/gsl_fit.h>

using namespace std;
int main (void)
{
    int n = 5;
    vector <double> x(5,0);
    vector <double> y(5,0);
    for(int i=0 ; i< 5; i++)
        x[i] = i*3.2; 

    for(int i=0 ; i< 5; i++)
        x[i] = i*2-11.6; 

    double c0, c1, cov00, cov01, cov11, sumsq;

    gsl_fit_linear (x, 1, y, 1, n, &c0, &c1, &cov00, &cov01, &cov11, &sumsq);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add that c++11 introduced the member function vector::data() that returns the raw pointer of the vector. What are the advantages of vector::data() over @king_nak method ?

1)  Clarity. This is subjective, but I think it is more elegant to use

```
 (...)
 gsl_fit_linear (x.data(), 1, y.data(), 1, n, &c0, &c1, &cov00, &cov01, &cov11, &sumsq);
 (...)
```

2)  const-correctness. vector::data() has an overload function that returns the const pointer when the function only needs to read the data

3)  Empty containers. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6485519/2472169) also cites the fact that it is ok to use vector::data even when the vector is empty. (it is not ok to send an empty container to gsl, but in general this is an extra good feature)

Answer (score 1):

The function `gsl_fit_linear` does not take a vector as input, but a `const double *`. You have to convert your vector to an array.

As vectors guarantee to store their elements in a continuous memory region (just as arrays), you can use a vector's data like an array. Just get a pointer to its first element:

```
double *xAsArray = &x.front();
```

**BEWARE**: If you change your vector (add/remove elements), the pointer will most probabely get invalid!

You should call your function like this:

```
sl_fit_linear (&x.front(), 1, &y.front(), 1, n, &c0, &c1, &cov00, &cov01, &cov11, &sumsq);
```