# C++ "pointer being freed was not allocated"

Tags: c++, pointers, fstream

The code is simple and as follow:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<void*> v;

    int a1 = 4;
    string a2 = "123";
    vector<int> a3 = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    int s1 = sizeof a1;
    int s2 = sizeof a2;
    int s3 = sizeof a3;

    v.push_back((void*)(&a1));
    v.push_back((void*)(&a2));
    v.push_back((void*)(&a3));

    fstream _f("test.bin", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    _f.seekp(0);
    _f.write((char*)(v[0]), s1);
    _f.write((char*)(v[1]), s2);
    _f.write((char*)(v[2]), s3);

    int r1;
    string r2;
    vector<int> r3;

    _f.seekg(0);
    _f.read((char*)(&r1), s1);
    _f.read((char*)(&r2), s2);
    _f.read((char*)(&r3), s3);

    cout << r1 << endl
         << r2 << endl
         << r3[0] << " " << r3[1] << " " << r3[2] << " " << r3[3] << endl;
    _f.close();
}
```

It will have the output below:

```
4
123
1 2 3 4
test(51104,0x7fff9c57d3c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe76fd00000:pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Command terminated
```

The output is good, but it says that "pointer being freed was not allocated", however, I don't have the `free()` operation in my code, I wonder why this would happen?

---

However, r2 doesn't have the same problem with r3, The code as follow works well.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<void*> v;

    int a1 = 4;
    string a2 = "123";
    vector<int> a3 = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    int s1 = sizeof a1;
    int s2 = sizeof a2;
    int s3 = sizeof(int)*a3.size();

    v.push_back((void*)(&a1));
    v.push_back((void*)(&a2));
    v.push_back((void*)(&a3));

    fstream _f("test.bin", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    _f.seekp(0);
    _f.write((char*)(v[0]), s1);
    _f.write((char*)(v[1]), s2);

    int r1;
    string r2;
    vector<int> r3;

    _f.seekg(0);
    _f.read((char*)(&r1), s1);
    _f.read((char*)(&r2), s2);

    cout << r1 << endl
         << r2 << endl;
    _f.close();
    v.clear();
}
```

output:

```
4
123
```

Comment: What do you think `_f.read((char*)(&r3), s3);` is doing?

Comment: You're corrupting the memory of the vector when you read into `&r3`. That causes undefined behavior.

Comment: I expect that `_f.read((char*)(&r3), s3);` is going to read s3 bytes from file "test.bin" from the position (s1+s2) to the end. Am I right?

Comment: @Chen No, you're wrong. To read into a vector use the `data()` member and assure the vector already is resized well.

Comment: Ask yourself what sizeof a2, sizeof a3 returns and why.

Comment: The same problem as with r3 is with r2.

Comment: I try it, but r2 seems that has not the same problem with r3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're causing undefined behavior when you write over the vector with:

```
_f.read((char*)(&r3), s3);
```

If you want a pointer to the array holding the vector data, you need to use `r3.data()`. And you can't use `sizeof r3` to get its size, that's the size of the `vector` object, not the underlying array.

```
int s3 = r3.size() * sizeof(int);
_f.read((char*)r3.data(), s3);
```

See [How to get std::vector pointer to the raw data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485496/how-to-get-stdvector-pointer-to-the-raw-data)

Comment: Got it, thanks! However, why r2 doesn't get the same problem as r3? I wonder it.

Comment: @ChenYuFan - Who said it doesn't? Try a much longer string. Then google "short string optimization".